# WPF: Change Style FontSize via DataTrigger on ComboBox selection

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, styles, font-size

I am new to XAML and WPF.
My purpose is to change all the FontSize of all my "text" controls, that appear in my window, via ComboBox.

[ComboBoxFontSize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyCe2.png)

i declared my style in my window:

```
       <Style x:Name="ControlBaseStyle" x:Key="ControlBaseStyle" TargetType ="{x:Type Control}">
           <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
           <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
           <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
       </Style>
       .
       .
       .
   </Window.Resources>
```

and i would like to link the first setter to my ComboBox:

```
               <ComboBox Name="CBFontSize" Style="{StaticResource ControlBaseStyle}" SelectedIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="CBFontSize_SelectionChanged">
                   <ComboBoxItem>8</ComboBoxItem>
                   <ComboBoxItem>9</ComboBoxItem>
                   <ComboBoxItem>10</ComboBoxItem>
                   <ComboBoxItem>11</ComboBoxItem>
                   <ComboBoxItem>12</ComboBoxItem>
                   <ComboBoxItem>14</ComboBoxItem>
                   <ComboBoxItem>16</ComboBoxItem>
                   <ComboBoxItem>18</ComboBoxItem>
                   <ComboBoxItem>20</ComboBoxItem>
                   <ComboBoxItem>22</ComboBoxItem>
                   <ComboBoxItem>24</ComboBoxItem>
               </ComboBox>
```

I tried setting the FontSize-Setter's Value via Binding, but it did not work:

```
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=CBFontSize}"/>
```

I tried setting it via DynamicResource (and use the CBFontSize_SelectionChanged to modify the value), but nothing happens:

```
       <Style x:Name="ControlBaseStyle" x:Key="ControlBaseStyle" TargetType ="{x:Type Control}">
           <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyFontSize}"/>
       </Style>


       private void CBFontSize_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           if (double.TryParse(CBFontSize.SelectedItem?.ToString() ?? "", out double mfs))
           {
               Resources["MyFontSize"] = mfs;
           }
       }
```

I tried setting it via DataTrigger, but i do not know how to pass the value:

```
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger x:Name="MyDataTrigger" Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=CBFontSize}">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=MyDataTrigger}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

Can someone help me?

PS i do not pretend that the solution has to follow my code/approach, any approach is fine to me.
I just imagine that there is a relatively simple solution i am too stupid/ignorant to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution.
I post it for anyone that could end up in the same situation:

```
    <Style x:Name="ControlBaseStyle" x:Key="ControlBaseStyle" TargetType ="{x:Type Control}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding ElementName=CBFontSize, Path=SelectedValue.Content}"/>
        .
        .
        .
    </Style>
```

my error was that i bound the SelectedValue of the ComboBox, that in my past experiences with WindowsForm contained the effective value, but in WPF the SelectedValue of a ComboBox is a ComboBoxItem, therefore i have to get the Content of that item.
Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find all controls in your window and set it's property FontSize to selected value in ComboBox.

```
private void FontSizeComboChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem?.ToString(), out var selectedFontSize))
        {
            foreach (var win in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                var allChildren = FindVisualChildren<Control>(win as Window);
                foreach (var c in allChildren)
                {
                    c.FontSize = selectedFontSize;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize?view=netframework-4.8